# Site graduated! New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/updated-april-14-design-for-academia-se).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://cdn.sstatic.net/academia/img/favicon.ico

http://cdn.sstatic.net/academiameta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: It's beautiful!! Thank you!!

Comment: oooh spiffy! (Just noticed a new icon on a question in the hot list, and came to investigate.)

Comment: Awesome everyone :)

Comment: I need to do some work to regain my reputation-earned moderator privileges (;

Comment: Thanks for the work. Looks really good in its final form.

Comment: Stéphane, I freely admit that I'm using an outdated browser, which may be the problem, but I'm seeing little to no difference in the color of Q titles for unvisited/visited. Should I see a difference? I like having a color or bold/normal change so I can quickly scan for Qs that I have or haven't visited yet.

Comment: Flat design, I love it!

Comment: That is such an elitist design. Academia is not defined by institutional buildings.

Comment: @user13107 I don't agree with either of your statements. 1) In many (western) countries, the majority of every year attends a university, so a campus is not elitist per se. 2) Arguably, it is; academia *does* overwhelmingly happen at physical universities. Also, the design should project some recognisable visualisation of the site topic which is not necessarily its definition (cf. [math.SE], [physics.SE], ...)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: How ironic, graduation of an Academia SE ;).