# Academia's question listing is taller

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

The entries in the question listing on Academia.SE are much bigger vertically than other SE sites. There appears to be a lot more spacing above and below each question entry.

[image: Academia versus SO]

Is there a reason Academia is different than most (all?) SE sites in regard to the question listing? I find it more difficult to scan and it requires more scrolling. The vast amount of emptiness makes me feel as if it is an oversight or a bug.

Can this be changed???

EDIT: This was also asked for in a [reply](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/910/746) on the original design post.

Comment: Hee. This ties in nicely to my casual observation that many academics consider white space to be wasted space, and that this relates to the horrible design values of most academic posters... ;-)

Comment: _many academics consider white space to be wasted space_ — As opposed to programmers?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a relatively simple fix—it's the extra padding around the question. However, I also think that the fix shouldn't be to go something *quite* so dense as [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). (Currently, I can fit about 7 questions from Academia.SE on my screen compared to about 10 SO questions in the same space. However, SO seems *too* crowded in comparison.

I think perhaps we can reduce the padding a bit, but we should still keep some just so that it remains easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

I also would prefer to see more questions at a glance (less scrolling => I am more happy).

Answer (score 3):

When I look at the two screenshots side by side, I prefer the academia spacing.  All in all, it is remarkable how much more pleasing to my eye the academia format is than the SO format: some really nice work was done in the design of our site.

It looks to me that the height of each question could be slightly reduced, perhaps to the point of being able to fit one more question on the screen.  But I wouldn't want to mess with it too much: all in all, I think that what has been pointed out here is truly a feature rather than a bug.