# Springer Shop uses an image quite similar to the Academia logo (or vice-versa)

Tags: discussion, design

After scrolling down in an email received from Springer, I stumbled across an image that looks undoubtedly similar to the Academia StackExchange logo. I made my little investigation, and found it again on the [Springer Shop website](http://www.springer.com/shop).

When the site was still in beta, [this post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/updated-april-14-design-for-academia-se) was created to discuss the future design. From what I know, this is where our logo comes from. Since I don't know if either our logo or their image is copyrighted (and have no legal knowledge anyway), I just wanted to highlight this *(possible) issue* to the community.

I know this is not much of a StackExchange question, but are the mods aware about this? If problematical, I do believe that this situation must be sorted as soon as possible.

Comment: *Since I don't know if either our logo or their image is copyrighted.* – Copyright is an automatic thing. If you create something (that is above the innovation threshold), you have the copyright.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft If you create something (that is above the innovation threshold), then, depending on circumstances, you _or your employer_ has the copyright.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to worry about:

1. The logos are not exactly identical, there is no copyright or attribution license issue.
2. It seems pretty clear from Springer's website that this drawing is not a registered trademark.
3. The image is rather generic and very similar instances can be found on stock design websites:

[image]

Comment: I thought the community would be better safe than sorry. Thanks for clarifying that.