# Which pictures belong to which university in the academia.stackexchange cover picture?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I can notice that the leftmost is MIT, the tallest one is UCBerkeley, but I couldn't figure out others. May be the second one from left is Cambridge.

Comment: They're just buildings that look like they might be typical university buildings. Many universities have a clock tower, for example, not only UC Berkeley.

Comment: @ff524 Still no one can deny that leftmost depicts MIT

Comment: You mean the one with columns? Again, many universities have such buildings. See e.g. [Columbia University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Memorial_Library).

Comment: Cambridge, England or Cambridge, USA?  Both are home to famous universities.

Comment: @gerrit yes, but for all I know the universities *in* Cambridge, MA are usually not referred to as "Cambridge." (Furthermore, one of them was already mentioned separately.)

Comment: To be more precise, they look a lot like the average USA-centric image of a university.

Answer (score 12):

I do not think that the buildings are intended to represent particular universities, instead the are just fictional buildings that look like university buildings.

You can read more about this in the post where the designers explained their design [UPDATED (APRIL 14): Design for Academia.se](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/updated-april-14-design-for-academia-se)